# Insert ... select output clause, get both INSERTED.ID and SELECTED.ID

Tags: sql-server

I am a duplicating a mindmap in my database. The structure is mindmap->nodes->links. ("->" is one to many).

The below snippet is duplicating the nodes.

```
DECLARE @mindmapNodes table(Id int, OldId int);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MindmapNodes]
(
    [MindmapId],
    [Loc],
    [Title],
    [SnippetId]
)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id
INTO @mindmapNodes
SELECT @mindmapId as [MindmapId]
    ,[Loc]
    ,[Title]
    ,[SnippetId]
FROM [dbo].[MindmapNodes] mindmapNodes
```

I need mindmapNodes.[Id] as OldId in the output clause. This will allow me to change [MindmapLinks].[From] and [MindmapLinks].[To] from the original node to the new duplicated node.

Is there a way to do this?

Tables:

```
SELECT [Id]
      ,[Name]
      ,[DateCreated]
      ,[DateModified]
      ,[OwnerId]
  FROM [dbo].[Mindmaps]

SELECT [Id]
    ,[MindmapId]
    ,[Loc]
    ,[Title]
    ,[SnippetId]
FROM [dbo].[MindmapNodes]

SELECT [Id]
      ,[From]
      ,[To]
      ,[FromPort]
      ,[ToPort]
      ,[MindmapId]
  FROM [dbo].[MindmapLinks]
```

[MindmapLinks].[From]

[MindmapLinks].[To]

Are foreign keys to [MindmapNodes].[Id]

Comment: Simply `OUTPUT inserted.Id, deleted.Id`?

Comment: @MK_ OUTPUT INSERTED.Id, DELETED.Id as OldId   ---- The multi-part identifier "DELETED.Id" could not be bound.

Comment: What do you mean by OldID? There is no such thing as an OldID here, it is an insert statement. And your code as posted would fail because you have more columns in your insert statement than the table.

Comment: Oh sorry nevermind my last comment. I made a mistake. It pretty much boils down to what @SeanLange just wrote.

Comment: @SeanLange it works, if i remove OldId, it's there so you guys can understand what i'm asking for. Old Id is the original id that I am duplicating. Basically SELECT [Id] From MindmapNodes is what I need as old id

Comment: Maybe you should post the tables and sample data along with the desired output. I just don't get what you are trying to do here. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: @seanlange it's not really table related.. is it possible to select a variable not being inserted from the select statement in the output clause

Comment: Yes it is possible. You put it in the OUTPUT clause. But it still is not clear to me what you are trying to do here. Is your variable the same value for every row? Not really sure how you can say that an insert with output is not table related.

Comment: @seanlange okay whats the syntax to get the id? I am duplicating the mindmap so yes all values stay the same I just need to change the foreign keys. In order to duplicate the links I need the original id and new id of the node the links point to.

Comment: Do you have it in a variable? I can't see your screen or read your mind. You have posted a minimal amount of code with zero context. If you actually posted some details like I suggested several posts above this would probably already be answered.

Comment: @seanlange i've appended the tables

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found an answer here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8cf1e38e-a29b-4ad7-abc7-b9fe2b987698/insert-into-using-select-with-output-into-multipart-identifier-could-not-be-bound?forum=transactsql

Tom:

> You can't use columns from the SELECT part of an INSERT ... SELECT in
>   the OUTPUT clause.  The only columns an INSERT statement can use in
>   the OUTPUT clause is columns in the inserted pseudo table. 
>   Fortunately, there is a way around this restriction.  Use MERGE to
>   simulate an INSERT by using an ON condition that is always false.

Here is the code:

```
select * 
into #temp
from [dbo].[MindmapNodes]
where [MindmapId] = 215

DECLARE @mindmapNodes table(Id int, OldId int);
MERGE INTO [dbo].[MindmapNodes]
USING #temp AS cf
ON 1= 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT
  ( [MindmapId],
    [Loc],
    [Title],
    [SnippetId]
  ) 
  Values
  (
    216,
    cf.Loc,
    cf.Title,
    cf.SnippetId
  )
Output inserted.[Id], cf.[Id] INTO @mindmapNodes;
```